# Searching in a result of selector with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Im tring to understand how can I get an inner object from already selected one.

I saw that the following should work:

```
$$(".a").forEach(element => {
  console.log( $(element).find(".price").clone() );
});
```

But, getting object not definded.
Whats the correct way to do that?

Comment: You probably wand `.filter` instead of `.find` - but without seeing your HTML, it's just a guess

Comment: @freedomn-m the $(element) object is not definded
can you provid a working example?

Comment: There's also two issues. Firstly jQuery has no `forEach()` method, it's just `each()`. In addition to that, the first argument is the index, the element is the second. Secondly, you seem to have aliased jQuery in the outer scope as `$$`, yet in the each loop you use only `$`

Comment: You can find working examples here:  https://api.jquery.com/filter/   For a more specific example to your needs, please provide at least some sample HTML and preferably a full [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Found an unswer.

The example above is corret, the problem was is that Jquery wan't loaded yet.

Note: `$$` are used when testing from chrome/firefox consul single `$` would result only the first match.
In the code you can use the single `$` sign.